# C# Entity Framework 5.0 Generic LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, generics

I am trying to use generics to load a record into my dbcontext cache.  I am using the following code.

```
_Context.Set<T>().Where(R => (int)R.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(R) == id).Load();
```

This code is throwing the following error and I cannot seem to figure out how to get around it.

System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetValue(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Is what I am doing possible or is there another way.

Comment: This would probably work if you have a base entity type, and add the trait `where T : BaseEntity`. Then you could just use `R.ID`.

Comment: Unforuntaley I need to use where T : class to access the dbset generically

Comment: I did find I could use the following code and it seems to add the record to the local cache, not sure if this is the right way to do it.   _Context.Set<T>().Find(id);

Comment: @SteveS - you can have both class and BaseEntity constraints.  `where T: BaseEntity, class`.  I agree with ta.speot.is that using a base entity type is a far better approach to this, and more stable.

Comment: @MystereMan Is there a good example of the BaseEntity solution?  I am very new to generics and my search results have been confusing at to how I would implement this in entity framework.

Comment: @SteveS - You just need to create a base entity that only has the ID, make sure all your other entities derive from it.  Then you use a BaseEntity constraint (`where T: BaseEntity, class`).  Then in your method you need only say `_Context.Set<T>().Where(R => R.ID == id)` which works because the compiler can guarantee that T is of type BaseEntity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're attempting to use Reflection methods (`GetType()`, `GetProperty()`, `GetValue()`) with LINQ to Entities, and it doesn't understand them.  The methods you're allowed to use inside a LINQ query are limited to what the query provider supports, and in the case of LINQ to Entities it's mostly things that can be translated into SQL relatively easily.

You won't be able to try to match the ID this way, unfortunately.  Using `.Find(id)` will work as long as the primary key for the entity type specified by `T` has a single column and `id` is the correct type, but that's going to be a very brittle approach even if it works in some cases.

If you describe your scenario a little bit more, people might have some good suggestions for another approach to take.  Can you explain why you want to do this generically?  It's pretty unusual to want to execute a query against your `DbContext` without knowing what entity type you're interested in.

Comment: *as long as the primary key for the entity type specified by T has a single column* Not true: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.103).aspx But correct that it is a brittle approach.

Comment: @ta.speot.is I meant that if you're only passing `Find()` one value (as in his example), then the primary key will also have to contain one column.  If you try to do `Find(id)` and the entity type has a compound primary key, it'll barf.

Comment: @Jeremy Todd, marked this as answered because it does answer my question, but I haven't found a better approach to the Find function.  I don't really understand the base entity concept

Comment: The main issue is that you're trying to query your database without knowing what entity type you're looking for.  If you knew that, you'd be able to make a LINQ query just by typing in the right property names, and not have to use reflection.  I'd say to try rewriting things to get rid of `T` and see if that makes anything clearer.